# GDB with pthreads

Tags: c, gdb, pthreads

I have a C program where the main function creates threads and I have to debug one thread. I am using gdb for he same. However I cannot "break" or "watch" variables on specific C files of this program. For eg. my thread 6 is programmed and uses certain C files and I have to break at line 601 on say call_connect.c. Is this not possible? If I try to, this is what happens:

```
(gdb) info threads
  6 Thread 0xb5c96b70 (LWP 3608)  0xb7fe1424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
  5 Thread 0xb6497b70 (LWP 3607)  0xb7fe1424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
  4 Thread 0xb6c98b70 (LWP 3606)  0xb7fe1424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
  3 Thread 0xb7499b70 (LWP 3605)  0xb7fe1424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
  2 Thread 0xb7c9ab70 (LWP 3604)  0xb7fe1424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
* 1 Thread 0xb7c9b6c0 (LWP 3603)  0x0804a178 in main ()

(gdb) break 601 thread 6
No line 601 in file "events.c".

(gdb) break call_connect.c:601 thread 6
No source file named call_connect.c.
```

Also I debugged my C code with -O0 -ggdb and still I can't watch variables.
This is what I get when I try to read a **char *ptext** variable.

```
(gdb) print ptext
No symbol "ptext" in current context.
(gdb) watch ptext
No symbol "ptext" in current context.
```

Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 3):

Although I have not extensively used `gdb` with `pthreads` but I have a few pointers which you might try out.

1. You can switch to the thread you want to debug using `thread threadnum` where `threadnum` is the id (first column) displayed through `info threads`.
2. Check the source directories being looked up for the file usinf `show directories` command. If the directory where your source resides is not in the list add it through `directory <path_to_source>` command
3. While setting the breakpoints or watch use auto completion (generally `<Tab>`) to look for breakpoints and watches you can set.

Please check links under *Thread Debugging* section in [YoLinux pthreads Tutorials](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html) for more details.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your program is compiled without debug info.

The most likely causes: either `call_connect.c` was compiled without `-ggdb` flag despite what you have claimed (examine your build log to verify that), or you have a "stray" `-s` on your link line (which would strip the executable).

Comment: Surely, `gdb` will tell you if it can't find the debug symbols once you've loaded up the binary ... ?  Isn't this a way to quickly verify if the binary has debug symbols or not?

Comment: GDB *is* telling you exactly that. What do you think `No source file named call_connect.c` mean?